# HAProxy loses client certificate after close

Tags: ssl, curl, haproxy, client-certificates

I set up HAProxy 1.5.14 to use client certificates. This works fine for a single request, but HAProxy seems to lose the client certificate after an HTTP close.

From the haproxy.conf:

```
frontend localhost_https
    bind *:8443 ssl crt /etc/private/server.pem.key_and_cert no-sslv3 ca-file /etc/certs/client_ca.pem verify required
    option forceclose
    default_backend my_http
```

I'm using forceclose to reliably trigger an HTTP close. Calling curl now shows that the first request authenticates correctly, but the second request does not.

```
$ (curl --cert /tmp/client.pem https://localhost:8443/ https://localhost:8443/ -vk > /dev/null) 2>&1|grep HTTP
> GET / HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> GET / HTTP/1.1
< HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Am I missing something? Why does HAProxy not send a request to the client to send the client certificate on the second request?